# Startup Application Python Program in Ubuntu stops running after a period of time

Tags: python, debugging, ubuntu, startup, pynotify

Here's the code. It runs for usually somewhere less than an hour and stops giving out the notifications or writing anything to the log file. The code is run as a Startup application on Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried adding exceptions for all kinds of errors in the hope of understanding why the program might be stopping, but to no avail. It just stops. And running it from the terminal used to work earlier, but even that has stopped giving results after a period of time.

```
import urllib2, os, time, sys, re, pynotify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from random import sample
from datetime import datetime

savepath = '/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/'
count = -1
iflp = True
innerct = 0
rndct = 0
rndct2 = 0 
flag = False
try:
    while(count < 1000):
        time.sleep(3)
        count = (count+1) % 30
        url = "http://www.insightsonindia.com/category/current-affairs-2"
        connect = False
        netcnct = True
        itntchk = 0
        while not connect:
            try:
                text = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.insightsonindia.com/category/current-affairs-2').read()
                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/log.txt', "a") as file:
                        file.write("{:%B %d, %Y - %H. %M. %S}".format(datetime.now()) + '\t\tIndicator of Something\n')
                connect = True
            except urllib2.URLError as e:
                itntchk = itntchk + 1
                if (itntchk > 20):
                    netcnct = False
                    with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/log.txt', "a") as file:
                        file.write("{:%B %d, %Y - %H. %M. %S}".format(datetime.now()) + '\t\tInternet Connection Issues\n')
                pass
        if (netcnct):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
            data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'post-thumbnail'})
            if count == 0:
                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/log.txt', "a") as file:
                    file.write("{:%B %d, %Y - %H. %M. %S}".format(datetime.now()) + '\t\tConnection Established After Sleep\n')
                for div in data:
                    links = div.findAll('a')
                    for a in links:     
                        if os.path.exists(savepath + 'urlist.txt'):
                            with open(savepath + 'urlist.txt', "r+") as file:
                                line_found = any(a['href'] in line for line in file)
                                if not line_found:
                                    file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
                                    connected = False
                                    while not connected:
                                        try:
                                            html = urllib2.urlopen(a['href']).read()
                                            connected = True
                                        except urllib2.URLError as e:
                                            pass
                                        else:
                                            file.write(a['href'] + '\n')

                                    sp = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

                                    txt = sp.get_text()

                                    realtxt = txt.encode('utf-8')
                                    s2 = "print PDFInsights "
                                    s3 = "Please Share This Post If You"
                                    dtxt = realtxt[realtxt.index(s2) + len(s2):realtxt.index(s3)]   
                                    if ('Current' in a.get('title')):


                                        p1 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Paper 1 Topic', dtxt)]
                                        p2 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Paper 2 Topic', dtxt)]
                                        p3 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Paper 3 Topic', dtxt)]
                                        p4 = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Paper 4 Topic', dtxt)]
                                        pre = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('Facts for Prelims', dtxt)]
                                        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/') if isfile(join('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/', f))]
                                        ltvr = []
                                        while(len(p4)>0):
                                            ltvr.append(min(p4))
                                            p4.remove(min(p4))
                                        while(len(p3)>0):
                                            ltvr.append(min(p3))
                                            p3.remove(min(p3))
                                        while(len(p2)>0):
                                            ltvr.append(min(p2))
                                            p2.remove(min(p2))
                                        while(len(p1)>0):
                                            ltvr.append(min(p1))
                                            p1.remove(min(p1))
                                        while(len(pre)>0):
                                            ltvr.append(min(pre))
                                            pre.remove(min(pre))

                                        i = 0
                                        ltvr.sort()
                                        while (i < len(ltvr)):
                                            if(dtxt[ltvr[i]+6]=='1'):
                                                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Paper1/' + a.get('title') + '.txt', "a") as file:
                                                    file.write(dtxt[ltvr[i]:ltvr[i+1]] + '\n')
                                            elif(dtxt[ltvr[i]+6]=='2'):
                                                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Paper2/' + a.get('title') + '.txt', "a") as file:
                                                    file.write(dtxt[ltvr[i]:ltvr[i+1]] + '\n')
                                            elif(dtxt[ltvr[i]+6]=='3'):
                                                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Paper3/' + a.get('title') + '.txt', "a") as file:
                                                    file.write(dtxt[ltvr[i]:ltvr[i+1]] + '\n')
                                            elif(dtxt[ltvr[i]+6]=='4'):
                                                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Paper4/' + a.get('title') + '.txt', "a") as file:
                                                    file.write(dtxt[ltvr[i]:ltvr[i+1]] + '\n')
                                            elif(dtxt[ltvr[i]+6]=='f'):
                                                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/' + str(len(onlyfiles)+1) + '.txt', "w+") as file:
                                                    file.write(dtxt[ltvr[i]:])
                                            i = i + 1

                                    elif ('Editorial' in a.get('title')):
                                        with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Editorials/' + a.get('title') + '.txt', "w+") as file:
                                                file.write(dtxt)
                        else:
                            with open(savepath + 'urlist.txt', "w+") as file:
                                file.write(a['href'] + '\n')
        if ((count == 0) or (netcnct == False)):
            innerct = (innerct + 1) % 2
            if (netcnct == False):
                innerct = 0
            if (innerct == 0):

                pynotify.init("Basic")
                onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/') if isfile(join('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/', f))]
                Tr = True
                Tre = True
                while (Tr):
                    if (rndct == 0):
                        rndn = sample(xrange(1, len(onlyfiles)), len(onlyfiles) - 1)
                    try:
                        filename = '/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/Pre/' + str(rndn[rndct]) + '.txt'
                        if (flag):
                            rndct = (rndct + 1) % (len(onlyfiles) - 1)
                            flag = False
                        lines = open(filename).read().splitlines()
                        if (rndct2 == 0):   
                            rnd2 = sample(xrange(1, len(lines)), len(lines) - 1)
                        while (Tre):
                            chk = rndct2    
                            rndct2 = (rndct2 + 1) % (len(lines) - 1)
                            if(rndct2 < chk):
                                flag = True
                            try:
                                if (lines[rnd2[rndct2]][0].isalnum()):
                                    Tre = False
                            except IndexError:
                                pass 
                        Tr = False
                    except (IOError,IndexError):
                        pass            
                with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/log.txt', "a") as file:
                    file.write("{:%B %d, %Y - %H. %M. %S}".format(datetime.now()) + '\tFileCt\t' + str(rndct) + '\t' + str(rndn[rndct]) + '\tLineCt\t' + str(rndct2) + '\t' + str(rnd2[rndct2]) + '\n')     

                n = pynotify.Notification("Fun Facts",
                  lines[rnd2[rndct2]]
                )

                n.show()
except Exception:
    with open('/mnt/8E1C30331C301923/PersonalAthul/CS/Insights/Current/log.txt', "a") as file:
                    file.write("{:%B %d, %Y - %H. %M. %S}".format(datetime.now()) + '\t\t Sorry bro') #+ sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: You may want to use Apache or Uwsgi server?